# how to the plural two nouns?

Tags: grammatical-number

How do a plural two nouns that are separated by an "and"?

Do I plural both words?

example: 
I import coffees and teas.
OR:
I import coffee and teas.

please advise.

Comment: It would be proper to say "I import coffee and tea".  If you say "I import coffees and teas", you're emphasizing that you are importing several (many?) varieties of coffee and of tea, and you might want to make that fact clearer by saying "I import various coffees and teas" or something similar.

Comment: You can't plural a word. But you can pluralize it or make it plural.

Answer (score 2):

The example you gave is a bit tricky. Normally someone would say *I import coffee and tea* because tea and coffee are [uncountable nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun). But maybe if you're talking about different *varieties* of coffee and tea, you could say *I import coffees and teas*.

To use countable examples, if you are importing multiple gems and minerals, you would say *I import gems and minerals* (both plural).